# Console application: Running a WebBrowser within a class that is running inside an STA Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control, console-application

I created a class that uses the WebBrowser control to scrape out some text data , it was initially running in a Windows Forms application , now I converted it to be a Console application , to do that I run my class in a thread and set it in STA , then inside my class I instantiate the WebBrowser with normal way using "new" keyword , my problem is when thread is completed it never really ends , and I enter endless waiting when I use Thread.Join() , and if I use Application.ThreadExit() nothing happens , so I tried Thread.Abort() , and this keeps throwing exceptions randomly , my question is what is the right way to run a class that needs to instantiate WebBrowser in a Console application.

This is how I create thread for my class:

```
var th = new Thread(() =>
{
    var br = MyBrowsingClass;
    br.NavigateTo(url);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
});
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start();
return th;
```

and inside my class I do the following :

```
wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(OnWebComplete);
CurrentState = Status.Navigating;
if (IsValidURL(GoogleQueryURL))
{
    wb.NavigateTo(GoogleQueryURL);
}
```

Comment: The problem with `Application.Run()` is that there can only be one instance. So parallel content retreiving can't be done easily. You can terminate the `Application.Run()` by calling `Application.Exit()` or create a 'dummy' form and pass it to the `Application.Run(form1)` and close it `form1.Close()`, but like I provided below, you should take a look at the `WebRequest` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `WebRequest` class, because I think you want the content instead of an interactive browser. This will eliminate the use of a messagepump (`Application.Run()`) with an extra thread.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request for the URL.        
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

**SOURCE** from msdn

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: the problem with webclient is that it retrieves raw html full of scripts . while web browser resolves every thing and gives a much better html result...so i want to stick to webbrowser control.i shall try using a dummy form then....thanks every one and I'll update the thread once i solve the issue